# hypothesis testing, P-value calculation, standard deviation unknown

Tags: hypothesis-testing

i have following problem,

"The null hypothesis says that a sprinter's reaction time follows a normal distribution with mean at most 0.150 seconds. Six measurements of a sprinter's reaction time show 0.152, 0.154, 0.166, 0.147, 0.161, and 0.159 seconds. What is the p value?"

i have calculated first sample mean as 0.157
and standard deviation under t-student distribution as 0.00686
then applying $t=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}$ i got 2.45

CDF of t(2.45) is around 0.973 which i believe is the p-value requested.

what wrong did i do?

Comment: It's $p=1-0.973$.

Comment: Yes p = 1 - cdf(t_score). thank you Michael.